# Java compiles my program, but I cannot run it

Tags: java, windows

I want to run a Java file with the following source code:

```
package u0a1;
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello World!");

    }

}
```

To run the file I did the following things:
`C:\.. \u0\u0a1> javac HelloWorld.java` (this works, class file is created)
 Then I try to run it with:

```
C:\..\u0> java u0a1.HelloWorld
```

This step doesn't work. Main class could not be found.

I also tried

```
C:\..\u0\u0a1> java HelloWorld
C:\..\u0> java u0a1\HelloWorld
```

None of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a piece i found somewhere else, worked for me.

> Have you set your JAVA_HOME correctly? If not you have to work with
>   the full path
>
> Example: `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javac.exe"
>   HelloWorld.java`
>
> If you have runtime issues, you should work it out like this
>
> Select MAIN directory - not package directory
>
> `java u0a1/HelloWorld`
>
> If you have problems with CLASSPATH or JAVA_HOME - try this:
>   `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javac.exe" HelloWorld.java`

source: http://quandano.com/questions/how-to-run-a-java-file-within-a-package-from-cmd

Answer (score 0):

You are compiling a program of package , so it should compile this way

**C:.. \u0\u0a1> javac -d . HelloWorld.java**

here -d for creating package u0a1

and "**.**"
for from current working directory

after compiling this way a folder will create with name "u0a1"

then other  thing will work properly